# Transfer function for Small signal model of inductor series peaking

Tags: analog, inductor

I am having problem understanding the Transfer function for Small signal model of inductor series peaking as shown below.

[image]            [image]

**However, how does this transfer function contribute to peaking since there are no "zeroes" at the nominator ?**

[image]

Retrieved from [A Wideband Low Power Low-Noise Amplifier in CMOS Technology](https://dr.ntu.edu.sg/bitstream/handle/10220/6280/A%20Wideband%20Low%20Power%20Low-Noise%20Amplifier%20in%20CMOS%20Technology.pdf?sequence=3)

Comment: If you derive `I(in)` to somehow result in a voltage across `C`, you have `Vo/Vin`. Or you could use `I(R)`, and then it's about currents. If `V-V` or `I-I` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Express the reactances in Laplace equivalent form. Then it's simple circuit analysis to give Vo/Iin

Comment: Usually \$H(s) = in/out =  V_{in}/V_{out}  or  I_{in}/V_{out}\$ I'll give you a hint \$ Z_L = L*s \$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Homework question with zero attempt to solve

Comment: this is not homework question. It is derived from figure 2 of the paper "A Wideband Low Power Low-Noise Amplifier in CMOS Technology"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using current divider rule: \$\small I_R=\large\frac{1/sC}{R+1/sC+sL}\small I_{in}=\large \frac{I_{in}}{s^2LC+sRC+1}\$

Hence: \$\small V_o=RI_R=\large \frac{RI_{in}}{s^2LC+sRC+1}\$

and: \$ \large\frac{V_o}{I_{in}}=\large \frac{R}{s^2LC+sRC+1}\$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no external load at Vo, you need to calculate the impedance seen by the current source. It's the parallel combination of C and (R in series with L): -

Z = \$\dfrac{\frac{R+sL}{sC}}{R+sL+\frac{1}{sC}}\$

Multiply through by sC to get: -

\$\dfrac{R+sL}{1+sCR+s^2LC}\$

So, your current source x the impedance above produces a voltage across C (Vc). To find Vo you have a potential divider problem: -

Vo = Vc\$\dfrac{R}{R+sL}\$

So,

\$I_{in}\times \dfrac{R+sL}{1+sCR+s^2LC}\times \dfrac{R}{R+sL} = V_o\$

So,

\$\dfrac{V_0}{I_{in}}=\dfrac{R}{1+sCR+s^2LC}\$

> Any help would be appreciated

I see little sign of that!